# bad class file using javac

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Some background: I'm a student just learning Java, and usually the professor handles making sure our assignments have the right class path. However, the whole semester I've been plagued by the same problem, and I still don't understand what's going wrong.

As an example, I have two files, **MyProgram.java** located in the folder "MyProject" and **MyProgramTest.java** located in the folder "ClassProject", which also contains "MyProject". `MyProgramTest` creates a `MyProgram` object and lets you test its functionality.

`MyProgramTest` has the line `import MyProject.MyProgram;` The compiling instructions my instructor gives is to use `javac MyProject/*.java` while in "ClassProject" which works fine. Then, we are to use `javac MyProgramTest.java` in the same directory. However, the compiler claims:

```
import MyProject.MyProgram;

bad class file: .\MyProject\MyProgram.class

class file contains wrong class: MyProgram

Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

So I don't quite understand why this is happening. **MyProgram** is in the **MyProject** directory, and that directory is in the folder I'm in. Since the instructor uses this exact method to compile these programs, I keep getting screwed since mine never compile correctly. Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or how I can fix the file to compile this way without changing the structure of the directories?

Comment: Did you remember to put `package MyProject` at the top of the `MyProgram.java` file?

Comment: What is your instructors input on this?

Comment: Please read [mcve]. Less descriptions of code - instead more of your code itself. Edit your question to provide that information.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure this:

The `MyProgram.java` file should contain this line at the top of the file:

```
package MyProject;
```

Compile `MyProgram.java` from the `ClassProject` folder:

```
javac -d . MyProject/*.java
```

Then Compile `MyProgramTest.java` from the same folder:

```
javac MyProgramTest.java
```

This will create the class files correctly in the appropriate folder structure.

This should solve your problem.

---

Hope this helps!